# what is the better way to create the dynamic shipment tracker through Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, html, css

[image: Shipment Tracker]

Am trying to create shipment tracker in Angular with HTML5 & CSS3. Can anyone advise how to create the above shipment tracker dynamically through Angular JS.

For now i have planned to start with  `ng-animate` for the tracker.

Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search.. i tried to use HTML Progress Bar for my tracking.

We can update the value of the progress based on your shipping status.
For now i have use `$interval` which updates the progress for every three second.

```js
var app = angular.module("progress_app", []);
 app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope, $interval){
 $scope.progress_value=5;

 $scope.heading="Shipping Tracker";
    $scope.callAtInterval = function() {
       if($scope.progress_value <=100){
  $scope.progress_value = $scope.progress_value * 2;
    }else{
  $scope.progress_value = 5;
    }
    
    }

    $interval( function(){ $scope.callAtInterval(); }, 3000);
 });
```

```css
.tracker {
   width:80%
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="progress_app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <h3 ng-bind='heading'> </h3><br/><br/>
  <progress value="{{progress_value}}" max="100" class="tracker">
  </progress>
</body>
</html>
```